# Error in rendering 3d text with Nuclex Framework (XNA)

Tags: c#, text, graphics, 3d, xna

When I try to load vector font using Nuclex Framework by writing this line in the Load method

```
this.vFont = this.Content.Load<VectorFont>("myFont");
```

where vFont is private vector font variable defined by

```
private VectorFont vFont;
```

I get this error 
" Error loading "myFont". File contains Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.SpriteFont but trying to load as Nuclex.Fonts.VectorFont. "

I know "myFont" is a Spritefont, but How can I define a vector font to be loaded ?!

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

The font has a wrong importer/processor set.

Select your font, goto the properties window and change it to the "VectorFont" importer/procesor from nuclex framework.

Be sure to have a nuclex content importer/processor project reference added to your content project.